# CSS Trouble with opacity

Tags: css, opacity

I have a psd file and I want to make psd to CSS. I tried to write header of psd which have `opacity` as in picture.[image]
 This is from my `index.html`
[image]

menu which contains `container` div. Second container which contains brand and menus

```
<nav class="menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="brand">
            <h1>Brandi</h1>
            <p>|    I’am your tag line</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

my css as written:

```
.menu{
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#000;
    -moz-opacity:.60; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:.60; 
}

.container{
    width:80%;
    height:70px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#brand{
    width:25%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
}

#brand>h1{
    color: #fff;
    float:left;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size : 28px;
}

#brand>p{
    color:#73797a;
    float:left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size : 13pt;
    margin-left:20px;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

As shown in figure `h1` element and `p` element also have `opacity` which I don't want. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: did you try opacity = 1 on your h1 and p

Comment: can you kindly prepare a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css for `.menu`

```
.menu{
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6); /* provide opacity here */
    /* remove the opacity properties below
    -moz-opacity:.60; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:.60; 
    */
}
```

Full Code -

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
/* applied opacity to nav.menu */
nav.menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
ul.menu {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#brand {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
#brand>h1 {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 28px;
}
#brand>p {
  color: #73797a;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13pt;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="brand">
      <h1>Brandi</h1>
      <p>| I’am your tag line</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: my problem solved but now container have opacity. %80 of menu have double opacity

Comment: what do you mean?? I can't understand? your container has 80% opacity?? then what you want?? please describe..

Comment: perhaps container div also have opacity.I want to give opacity only nav element.

Comment: you don't want the black background of `container` `div`?? which seems to double opacity of `.menu`???

Comment: I want to make same color menu and container div.Now container div look like more black than menu

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz if you want to make some colored menu then add background-color to your `ul.menu` it will work and will not appear black. actually there was a little problem with my code which I have corrected, the problem occured because your nav and ul both have class menu. check my updated code

Comment: what did you mean some colored menu.I want to make same color them(ty for help)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88684/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-tarik-akyuz).